# CSS how to translate an image up, and have the div adjust to the new size?

Tags: html, css

I'm working on this block of HTML CSS, I need the image to overlap slightly the header div (in blue).

I'm doing this as shown in the jsfiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/49zcmf4z/3/

the HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 block-header">
      <div class="col-md-offset-6 col-md-6 text-center block-header">
        <h1>Title</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 image text-center">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="content">
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and the CSS

```
body {
  margin: 10px;
}

.container {
  border: solid 1px red;
}

.image {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
}
@media (min-width: 200px) {
  .image img {
    transform: translateY(-5em);
  }
}
.image img {
  width: 100%;
  border: solid 1px black;
  margin-left: 1em;
}

.block-header {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 85px;
  padding-left: 0px;
  padding-right: 0px;
}
@media (max-width: 992px) {
  .block-header {
    padding-top: 1px;
  }
}
.block-header h1 {
  color: white;
}
```

my problem is that after translating up the image, the div that contains it remains unchanged, and has lots of white space in the place where the image used to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey you could try to use margins instead of transform, it's easier :

```
.image {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
  @media (min-width: 200px) {
    img {
      margin-top: -5em;
    }
  }
  img {
    width: 100%;
    border: solid 1px black;
    margin-left: 1em;
  }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/49zcmf4z/4/

Answer (score 0):

You can always "hardcode" the margins of the image (probably not best solution):

```
  img {
width: 100%;
border: solid 1px black;
margin-left: 1em;
margin-bottom: -4em;}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/49zcmf4z/5/